# React Native app with Google App Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

Sorry, It's duplicate. But I did not get any comments in other one, that's why making another post...

Im planning to build a React Native App and have the backend API hosted on google I want to use MySQL, so no Firebase for me (unless Firebase has a relational DB i can use?)

Basically I want to create some PHP API on Google App Engine that my App can call and receive JSON responses (i have no idea how it works, can i just stick CodeIgniter in it? Do i need Endpoints? Or is that just another abstraction off App Engine?)

Was just wondering if anyone has done this yet (is it doable? any awesome libraries I can just npm?) and could share some experience?

Comment: [Rest Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) help you to make API's

Comment: thanks... I have fixed it... we need to use app engine or compute engine...